# Line by line parsing a huge XML file by a light weight parser

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

I'm writing a small stand alone tool for Linux which needs read a huge xml-file.

The xml-file has simple structure and a progressive or streaming (line by line) parser is suitable for it.

I want to use a light-weight class library such as TinyXML but I don't know it supports progressive parsing or not?!

If the answer is "yes", Do you have a sample? And, if the answer is "no", Do you know another alternative for it which is small and header only class library?

**Update:** How about RapidXML or pugiXML?

Comment: By progressive parser I guess you mean a streaming parser. The normal term for this in XML is a SAX parser. From a quick look at the TinyXML web-site I don't think its a SAX parser. It's the other kind of XML parser, a DOM parser. In other words it reads the entire document in memory.

Comment: I am afraid, john is right about TinyXML being not capable of streaming parsing. If you need portable library, take a look at Xerces which has SAX APIs (streaming parsing).

Comment: I have always liked the expat parser because it is small and simple. http://expat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like libxml's [XmlReader interface](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html) is just what you want. Fast, simple, and streaming. Light-weight and XML don't mix, unfortunately. I prefer XmlReader's pull model to SAX's push model, but they'll both do what you want.

In the pull model, you call a function and get a new node, then check yourself if it matches. In the push model, you supply callbacks and SAX calls them as it finds nodes matching them.

TinyXML, last I checked, is not standards-compliant -- I would avoid it.